# Laravel collectivehtml secure route or url

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravelcollective

in my view page I have this route:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'forumcomment/' . $forum->slug, 'files'=>false, 'id' => 'qw-commentform' ,'class' => 'qt-clearfix'])   !!}

        <hr class="qt-spacer-s"><div class="input-field">
        {!! Form::textarea('comment', null, ['class'=>'materialize-textarea', 'id'=>'my-editor', 'required'=>'required','aria-required'=>true]) !!}
        <label for="comment" class="">Comment*</label></div>
        <hr class="qt-spacer-s">
      {!! Form::submit('Post Comment', array( 'class'=>'qt-btn qt-btn-primary qt-btn-xl' )) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

getting mixed content error How can I get a secure route?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Show your route too.

Comment: mix content on https:// route and block some files

Comment: its not giving me green secure https:// on top left because of this form i tried with route name still same error

Comment: Serve everything (page and assets) as `https`…

Comment: yeah everything is on https only getting error on form

Comment: Open browser console, it should show the url that was loaded over `http`, or at least explain what it is not secure.

Comment: its showing me mixed content posting on http instead https

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this to the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`.
This loads all content over `http` on `local` development and `https` on `production`

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', $this->app->environment() != 'local');
```

and always change your `environment` to `production` on production.